# Sum 4 numbers, 1 bit each, with three full adders

Tags: adder, binary, summing

My excercise is the following:

```
Make a circuit which sums 4 binary numbers, one bit each, with three full adders.
```

My solution was the following (sorry I can't draw here).
Let the numbers be a,b,c,d.

**First FA:**
**Entries: a,b, '0' as carry in. (first addition, no need for carry in).**

**Second FA:**
**Entries: sum of a,b from first FA, c, carryIn: carry out from first FA.**

**Third FA:**
**Entries: sum of second FA, d, carryIn: carry out from second FA.**

I would ask your kind help to let me know if my solution is correct. Furthermore, if you can suggest a better solution, please do.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you express 1+1+1+1 in 2 bits?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I represent them in 3 bits, don't I? The highest result I can get is 100.

Comment: Which are your 3 outputs?

Comment: Hmmmm... I see, my output is just my one bit sum. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: You can get a 3 bit output. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is wrong. The output of your 1st FA is `a+b`. the output of your 2nd FA is `LSB(a+b) + MSB(a+b) + c`. Which is wrong.

**Solution:**
What we want is `a+b+c+d`. so produce the sum `a+b+c` using one FA. use second FA to add `d` with this sum. this will give the LSB of output. Adding carries of these FA's will give the MSB's. Use the 3rd FA to get the MSB's. See the figure given below.

[image]

A,B,C and D are the inputs.
Y2 is the MSB of output, Y0 the LSB and Y1 is the second LSB of output.

Comment: thank you. Can you please explain what are MSB, LSB? @nidhin

Comment: @Alan When 4 bits are added we need 3 bits to represent the result. because it can have value atmost `100`. Out of these 3 bits, the right most bit which is having least significant value is called least significant bit ([LSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit)) and the left most bit is called the most significant bit ([MSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit))

Comment: @Alan - On a larger scale (bytes rather than bits), the question of MSB / LSB has provoked a great deal of angst, generally referred to a the BigEndian/LittleEndian War. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness for an intro. Just thought you'd find it interesting.